# on which floor does she lives?

Tags: puzzle

A woman lives in a 36 floor building. There is a lift in that building. When she leaves her aprtment and goes to lift,there are 3 times chances lift will take her up than take her down(3:1,up:down)..On which floor she lives?

Kindly help with the question.

Comment: Why this question was asked ??

Answer (score 0):

She lives on floor 9. Divide 36 by 4 (ratio 3:1) = 9. Because it is more likely to go up, it means there are more levels above than below.

Therefore the answer is floor 9.

Comment: Doesn't that assume that people travel randomly between floors instea of mostly from/to ground floor?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The question is ambiguous...I believe the question is mathematical and not practical and you are intended to assume that people are more likely to travel to areas where there are more floors possible.